# Determine the ring homomorphism with domain $\mathbb{Q}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Determine all the ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$  and  $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$

**My attempt** : Ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Here $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic  and we know that any ring homomorphism send $1$ to $1$

So $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$  send each integer  $n$ to the rational number $\frac{n}{1}$

This implies  identity is the only such homomorphism  from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

But here im  confused  that how  to determine the ring homomorphism  from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}?$

Comment: You got the first part right, though the unique ring homomorphism is strictly speaking the inclusion, not the identity. For the second part, assume $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism, what can you say about $f(1/2)$?

Comment: @Thorgott $f(1/2)= f(1).\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: No, you got the first part (subtly) wrong!  A ring homomorphism sends $1\mapsto 1_I$, where $1_I$ is $1$ _in the image_.  This is usually $1$ in the codomain, but there's one special case in which it is not... _(hint, hint)_.

Comment: @Thorgott $f(1/2)=1/2$ that  mean  idenitity is the only such homomorphism . Am i right ?

Comment: I don't know an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ that's called $1/2$, take a step back.

Comment: oh !! my bad thinking. @Thorgott      I think $f(1/2)=f(1.\frac{1}{2})=f(1) .f(\frac{1}{2})=1.0=0$  Am i right ?

Comment: @JacobManaker  that mean  there are two  ring homomorphism from  $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ i,e if $ f(1)=0$  , then  $f(x)=0 $for all $x $